# Use PHP variable to search through SQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, post, web-scripting

I have a database called $addressdb. I want to search through a table on that database with a result the user inputted ($usersName). My mistake is probably really stupid. I am new with mySQL.

```
<?php

//IF THE LOGIN is submitted...
if ($_POST['Login']){
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "addressdb";
    $usersName = $_POST['users'];

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT userID, userName FROM users WHERE userName =$usersName";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

...

My line of error is

```
$sql = "SELECT userID, userName FROM users WHERE userName =$usersName";
```

More specifically the variable call.

Comment: enclose `$userName` in single quotes : `userName ='$usersName'`

Comment: I always prefer to use `WHERE userName='".$username."'`

Answer (score 1):

Best approach is :

```
$sql = "SELECT userID, userName FROM users WHERE userName ='".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $usersName)."'";
```

Here it is not so applicable since you are passing the plain text. But when taking data from html page you should use this way.

Comment: This is a great approach. I haven't tried this yet but by the looks of it, it looks for much better than messing around with single quotes and double-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
$sql = "SELECT userID, userName FROM users WHERE userName = '".$usersName."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use quotes around your $userName.

```
$sql = "SELECT userID, userName FROM users WHERE userName = '$usersName'";
```

But to be clear, you should escape your user input at least with `mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $userName);`